# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like

Tags: python, csv

I was working on a code  and the error occurred on the first line of 
the for loop block , the corpus variable was still updated by some entries even though the error occurred 
please help me remove this error

```
for i in range (0 ,N):
    data = re.sub('[^a-z A-Z]','',reciept['subject'][i])
    data=data.lower()
    data=data.split()
    data=[word for word in data if word not in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
    ps=PorterStemmer()
    data=[ps.stem(word) for word in data if word not in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    data=' '.join(data)
    corpus_recipt.append(data)
```

the error says as follows
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you edit the question to tell us what the code should be doing and paste the error trace in full?

Comment: The error should tell you what line of code is throwing it. That part is big, can you include it please?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the issue is `reciept['subject'][i]` is not pulling a string. You could throw a quick `print(reciept['subject'][i])` in before that line and check.

Comment: the loop works for 138 enteries out of 31000 entries but does not when nan is encountered .

Comment: by what should i replace nan and how?

Comment: i ran df1 = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True) and after that the above loop it worked thanks for your help :)

Comment: That's between you and your god, but my first impulse is just to skip those lines.